# Fixing DNS on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, dns, hosts, ubuntu-server

I've got a server that is currently running as servername, but I need it to be servername.domain.com (the IP already resolves to servername.domain.com), and I currently have:

```
0.0.0.0 servername.domain.com
```

in /etc/hosts. What else do I need to do to get the server set up with the IP correctly?

This is the first time I've done anything like this - I can be more specific if needed.

If this is the wrong place to be posting this - please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Does your /etc/hosts really have the IP as 0.0.0.0, or is that something that you are using as a placeholder? What is the output of the `hostname` command.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a placeholder. servername is the output of hostname.

Comment: So is the problem that you are trying to solve that servername.domain.com doesn't resolve from an additional host? or that the FQDN doesn't resolve from the server itself? Or is it more basic than that? Can you provide the output from a command that is problematic (other than `hostname`)?

Comment: the IP resolves to servername.domain.com, however hostname lists servername, so it appears the server doesn't know it's real name (if that's the way to put it). This seems to be problematic for things such as running a mailer daemon.

Comment: So if you ping server.domain.com from the server itself, it responds appropriately? None of my mail servers show their FQDN at the `hostname` command, or at the shell prompt. However, they all know what their FQDN is, and are able to reach it appropriately. Which mail server are you looking at?

Comment: `hostname` is _supposed to_ only list the name, not the FQDN.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to go to another computer and type `ssh servername.domain.com` or point a web-browser at http://servername.domain.com, you should find your *local* DNS server (if any) and add the entry there to the DNS configuration files. If you don't have a *local* DNS server then you need to add the entry to every computers `hosts` file.

On the Ubuntu server you can add the domain to /etc/resolv.conf but there's probably a handy GUI configuration tool for doing this.